# Difference between left and right conjugation and commutativity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In group theory, through the book of Dummitt and Foote, how is the idea of ​​right and left conjugation different from commutation?

The difference between them is not clear to me, as conjugation appears to imply commutativity, even if it is just left conjugation.

Ex.: Regarding the commutativity of the conjugation, $gag^{-1}$ on the left implies $g^{-1}ag$ on the right, that is, $gag^{-1} = g^{-1}ag$? Thus, $[g^{-1}a]g = g[ag^{-1}]$, which is the commutation property, whether for $ga = ag$ or for $g^{ -1}a = ag^{-1}?$
Or does $gag^{-1}$ not necessarily mean $g^{-1}ag$, which makes $ga \neq ag$ and $g^{-1}a \neq ag^{-1}$ under the conjugation? This doubt arises due to the definition of centralizer and normalizer and the difference between them.

[Definition of centralizer according to the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMyRu.jpg)

The definition of centralizer of a non-empty subset $A$ of a group $G$ is performed by left conjugating the element $a$ of $A$ with an element $g$ of $G$: $C(G) = \{g \in G \mid gag^{-1}\forall a \in A\}$. $gag^{-1}$ if and only if $ga = ag.$

[Definition of centralizer according to the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gELu.jpg)

The center of $G$ is described through the commutativity of an element $g$ of $G$ with an element $x$, also of $G: Z(G) = \{g \in G \mid gx = xg \forall x \in G\}.$

[Definition of center according to the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAZ00.jpg)

The normalizer of $G$ is similar to the centralizer of $G$, however, it is described only by the conjugation of the element $a$ of $A$ in $G$ by $g$, which also belongs to $G,$ without commutativity: $N(A) = \{g \in G \mid gAg^{-1} = A\}.$

[Definition of normalizer according to the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bh8q.jpg)

So, would the centralizer be defined by conjugation associated with commutativity? Different from the normalizer, which is only defined by conjugation, and the center, which is only defined by commutativity?

Comment: Conjugation is an action. So if you left conjugate by g on an element a, that's $g^{-1}ag$. When that is equal to $a$, then $g$ commutes with $a$ (or "is commutative with" $a$).

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The centralizer of S is the set of elements of the group that fix each element of S under conjugation, whereas the normalizer is the set of elements that satisfy the weaker condition of leaving the set S fixed under conjugation.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 0):

The operation of "commutation" is not a standard term in group theory, but (although I don't have a copy of Dummit and Foote at hand, so this is an educated guess) one could motivate the action of a group on itself by left (or right) conjugation by describing the action of an element $g\in G$ on an element $h\in G$ as "the effect of *commuting* $g$ past $h$: that is, if I want to 'commute $g$ past $h$ going left to right' I find:
$$
g.h = (ghg^{-1}).g = \ell_g(h).g
$$
so that the action on $h$ is given by the *left-action* of $G$ on itself by conjugation, $\ell_g(h) = ghg^{-1}$, whereas if I 'commute $g$ past $h$ going right-to-left' then I get
$$
h.g = g(g^{-1}hg) = g.r_g(h)
$$
that is, the action on $h$ is the *right-action* of $G$ by conjugation on itself, $r_g(h) = g^{-1}hg$.

Here $g\mapsto \ell_g$ is a left action of $G$ on itself because $\ell_{g_1g_2} = \ell_{g_1} \circ \ell_{g_2}$ and $g \mapsto r_g$ a right action because $r_{g_1g_2} = r_{g_2} \circ r_{g_1}$.

That said, when it comes to the definition of centralizers and normalizers, one can use *either* of the conjugation actions in the definition, essentially because for any $g,h\in G$ we have $\ell_g(h) = r_{g^{-1}}(h)$:

For example, if $h \in G$ we can define the centralizer of $h$ to be the stabilizer of $h\in G$ for the left-conjugation action, that is
$$
\begin{split}
\text{Stab}_{G,\ell}(h) &= \{g \in G: \ell_g(h)=h\} = \{g \in G: r_{g^{-1}}(h)=h\} \\
&= \{g \in G: g^{-1} \in \text{Stab}_{G,r}(h)\} = (\text{Stab}_{G,r}(h))^{-1}\\ 
&= \text{Stab}_{G,r}(h)
\end{split}
$$
Since the centralizer of a subgroup is just the intersection of the centralizers of its elements, so if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then you obtain the same notion of centralizer whether you use the left or right conjugation action.

The normalizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is the stabilizer of the subgroup under the left or right conjugation action for the same reason, as is the centre.